# How to create a Shared Folder using Powershell and set permissions

Tags: powershell, permissions, folder

I want to create a shared folder using PowerShell and then want to set permission on it as follows:

1. Farm account: Full access
2. Application pool account: Full access
3. Everyone or Authenticated users: Read

What will be the possible powershell command to accomplish this?

Comment: what you mean by Shared Folder? is it under any document library?

Comment: No, These folders will be created under physical drive like C:\

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a SharePoint specific issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is the Create folder command:

```
New-Item "C:\Shared" –type directory
```

If you are creating multiple levels at once (like "C:\NewRootFolder\NewChildFolder\NewShared" you can add the –force switch to make it create all necessary parent folders in the heirarchy)

Now that you have a folder that you want to share, you can turn it into a shared folder using the New-SMBShare cmdlet.

```
New-SMBShare –Name "Shared" –Path "C:\Shared" `
 –ContinuouslyAvailable `
 –FullAccess domain\admingroup  `
 -ChangeAccess domain\deptusers `
 -ReadAccess "domain\authenticated users"
```

[New-SmbShare on Microsoft official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbshare?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's about SharePoint, but to share folder from cmd You don't need PS, You can use standard **net share** command:

```
@Echo off
ECHO Creating your sharing folder and network discovery
NET SHARE Upload=D:\Upload /GRANT:everyone,FULL
ECHO Your Upload folder is now available for sharing folder
ECHO.
NET SHARE Downloads=D:\Downloads /GRANT:everyone,READ
ECHO Your Download folder is now available for sharing folder
exit
```